# Finding function from the graph

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

[Flux and angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR1VR.png)
[added theta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5oaK.jpg)

Given the above graph, I have to find the relation between $u_i$ and $\phi$.
I need insight on how to relate these two graphs and come to the derivation as shown below:
[derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW8yA.jpg)

Comment: $u_i$ is clearly the derivative of $\phi$.

Comment: When we ignore the continuous line and retain the dashed line in second part, $-u_i$  is an obvious derivative of $ldB\; \varphi$.

Comment: alright. I find the function for every piecewise continuous graph which gives me the following result:Φ=-B∙A,
Φ=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-π/2), 
Φ=B∙A ,
Φ=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-3π/2) ,
Φ=-B∙A
and let me  find the derivative of flux with respect to angle first which gives me:

Comment: dΦ/dϕ=(2B∙A)/(π-2θ),
dΦ/dϕ=-(2B∙A)/(π-2θ)
for two slopes

Comment: and derivative of flux w.r.t time comes out to be:                                      
 (dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt,
(dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt,
  where dϕ/dt=2πn

Comment: I am still not getting the derivation that my professor derived.

Answer (score 0):

The three discontinuous $-u_i$ regions (slopes are zero, positive, zero, negative,zero ) are integrated with respect to time getting continuous function $\varPhi$ but with discontinuous slope/rate jumps as shown.